# How to load a worker script file into Next.js from an external module, without manually copying it to the public folder?

Tags: webpack, next.js

I have tried these things in my next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
import MonacoWebpackPlugin from 'monaco-editor-webpack-plugin'
import CopyPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin'
import createMDXPlugin from '@next/mdx'
import withYaml from 'next-plugin-yaml'
import path from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'
import remarkPrism from 'remark-prism'
import rehypeSlug from 'rehype-slug'
import remarkMath from 'remark-math'
import rehypeKatex from 'rehype-katex'

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

if (
  process.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH == null ||
  !process.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH.includes(
    `${process.env.PWD}/node_modules/canvas/build/Release:`,
  )
) {
  process.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH = `${
    process.env.PWD
  }/node_modules/canvas/build/Release:${
    process.env.LD_LIBRARY_PATH || ''
  }`
}

const mdxConfig = {
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    providerImportSource: '@mdx-js/react',
    rehypePlugins: [[rehypeSlug], [rehypeKatex]],
    remarkPlugins: [[remarkPrism], [remarkMath], [remarkGfm]],
  },
}

const withMDX = createMDXPlugin(mdxConfig)

const nextConfig = withYaml(
  withMDX({
    swcMinify: true,
    transpilePackages: [
      '@termsurf/vine',
      '@textsurf/chat',
      'react-syntax-highlighter',
    ],
    pageExtensions: ['mdx', 'md', 'tsx', 'ts'],
    poweredByHeader: false,
    trailingSlash: false,
    webpack: (config, options) => {
      config.experiments = {
        asyncWebAssembly: true,
        syncWebAssembly: true,
        layers: true,
        topLevelAwait: true,
      }
      config.resolve.fallback = {
        fs: false,
        path: false,
        dns: false,
        net: false,
        tls: false,
      }

      config.resolve = {
        ...config.resolve,
        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
        },
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'],
      }

      config.plugins ??= []

      if (!options.isServer) {
        config.plugins.push(
          new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
            languages: [
              'json',
              'markdown',
              'css',
              'typescript',
              'javascript',
              'html',
              'graphql',
              'python',
              'scss',
              'yaml',
            ],
            filename: 'static/[name].worker.js',
          }),
        )
      }

      config.plugins.push(
        new CopyPlugin({
          patterns: [
            {
              from: path.resolve(
                path.join(
                  __dirname,
                  './node_modules/libarchive.js/dist',
                ),
              ),
              to: path.resolve(
                path.join(__dirname, './public/libarchive'),
              ),
              force: true,
            },
          ],
        }),
      )

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.wasm$/,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      })

      // TODO: improve this function -> track https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25852
      if (options.isServer) {
        config.output.webassemblyModuleFilename =
          './../static/wasm/[modulehash].wasm'
      } else {
        config.output.webassemblyModuleFilename =
          'static/wasm/[modulehash].wasm'
      }

      config.resolve.alias.canvas = false

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(
            path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/libarchive.js/dist'),
          ),
        ],
        loader: 'file',
      })

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(glsl|vs|fs|vert|frag)$/,
        type: 'asset/source',
      })

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(txt|node)$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
      })

      return config
    },
  }),
)

export default nextConfig
```

Specifically, the `CopyPlugin`, and the `file` loader with the libarchive.js path.

1. The `CopyPlugin` isn't writing anything to the public folder when I start the dev server and load a page.
2. If I visit `/worker-bundle.js` in the browser it 404s.
3. The `file` loader isn't producing the path.

How do I get it to either copy to the public directory, or to give me the path so I can load it manually via a `new Worker(path)`?

This is to load a script in a dist directory (or other place), *within* a nested node_modules package, not something that is directly in a relative place in my Next.js app.